# Command line build for Eclipse - dependent projects

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, qnx, momentics

I am using an Eclipse based IDE (QNX Momentics.)  I have several projects in my workspace.  I have Project A, B and C. Project C has dependencies on Project A and B.  If I go into the IDE and properties of "C" and Project References, and I check A and B, then I can go and do a "build" of C, and it will build A and B if they aren't already built.  This works fine in the IDE.  If I do a clean, and go out to a command line, and do a "make" under the C project, then it does not compile A and B, and thus gives me some errors. (can't find certain library files).  I see a  flag that has "A" and "B" projects in the .project file, but I don't see any rules anywhere to instruct it to build. Any help on this is appreciated.  By the way, this is a C++ project if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I can build referenced projects whereas they are cleaned. I suppose your C project is a makefile project. So, it may change the behavior of the IDE.
Momentics creates a runtime makefile for "QNX C/C++ Project" type. Therefore, you cannot see all rules.

Comment: "makefile project"? I don't know what that means.  It has a makefile, but it's not just a makefile.  I've since just written a script to simply build in the order I need; but if someone knows how to modify the make/environment files to do this, then that would be good to know for the future.

Comment: If the project settings (include paths, library dependencies, etc.) are in a "Makefile" then your project is a makefile project. If the settings are stored in ".cproject" the project is a managed project. Anyway, Momentics IDE has a special project type named "container project". You can build projects in a custom order using that project type.